Does the inequality $\iint_{\mathbb R^2} \frac{|f(x)|^2}{|x-y|^a} \ dy\,dx\le k ||f||_{L^2(\mathbb R)}^2$ hold?
I am solving an exercise about integration in dimension 2 and I am stuck at this point.
Suppose that $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$ and let $a\in (1, 2)$. Consider the integral
$$\iint_{\mathbb R^2} \frac{|f(x)|^2}{|x-y|^a} \ dy\,dx.$$
I would like to prove that
$$\iint_{\mathbb R^2} \frac{|f(x)|^2}{|x-y|^a} \ dy\,dx\le k ||f||_{L^2(\mathbb R)}^2,$$
for a positive constant $k$.
There is any trick which can allow me to state that the previous inequality hold?
I have tried the integration by parts, cauchy-schwarz inequality, divide the integration domain. Nonetheless, I am still not able to find a way to get the desired inequality.
Do you have any hint?

"I'm solving a very hard..."                           A random MSE user: And I have taken that personally

Just to say that I find the exercise to be very hard for my current level of math. I can remove that part if it bothers you so much or if it offends someone's sensibilities.

$|x-y|^a$ clearly blows up whenever $x=y$. Do you have any good reasons to believe that the bound you're looking for is true?

To embark on @Oscar's thoughts: This bound would imply that $\int_{[-\varepsilon, \varepsilon]^2} \tfrac{1}{\lvert x - y \rvert^a}~\mathrm{d}(x, y) < \infty$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$. My quick Fubini computations (that could be off) tell me that this does not hold.

This looks very similar to some sort of fractional Sobolev seminorm, in which case the numerator would be $f(x) - f(y)$. Can you give a bit more context on where you encountered this integral? If it comes from that setting, it may be just a typo.

It was just a joke :)

For $f\neq 0$ the left hand side is equal $\infty,$ as
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty|f(x)|^2\left [\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty{dy\over |x-y|^\alpha}\right ]\,dx\\ =\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty|f(x)|^2\left [\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty {dy\over |y|^\alpha}\,dy\right ]\,dx=\infty$$
The function $f$ does not matter at all as long as it is nonzero. So no inequalities may help.

Your estimate is a special case of the weak Young-inequality (used in Potential theory) which follows from the Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality, see the first answer of
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181669/generalized-hardy-littlewood-sobolev-inequality
It holds that
$$
\iint \frac{\vert f(x) \vert^2 }{ \vert x-y\vert ^a} \, dy \,  dx =
\Vert \, \vert \cdot \vert^{-a/2} * f \Vert_2  \leq C \Vert f \Vert_p.
$$
The exponent $p$ depends on $a$ via (we use $n=2$):
$$
1/p + a/4 = 1 + 1/2.
$$

The inequality does not help. In order to apply HL you need to estimate something of the form $$\int\left (\int {|f(x)|^2\over |x-y|^a},dx \right )^pdy$$ with $p>1$

Jacob Körner, +1, though. Thanks!

thanks, that's true

The claim as stated is not true.
Suppose that $f$ can be reduced to a single variable function, i.e $\exists \phi:\mathbb R_{\geq 0}\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=\phi(|x|).$ Now see that
$$\Vert f\Vert^2_{L^2(\mathbb R)}=\int_{\mathbb R^2}|f(x)|^2\mathrm d^2 x=\int_0^\infty \int_{\partial\mathbb B(0,r)}|f(x)|^2\mathrm d^1x~\mathrm dr \\ =\int_0^\infty {\phi(r)}^2~2\pi r~\mathrm dr<\infty$$
This means that the function $\psi(r)={\phi(r)}^22\pi r$ satisfies $\psi\in L^1(\mathbb R_{\geq 0})$.
Now suppose for instance $y=0$ and consider your integral in question:
$$\int_{\mathbb R^2}|f(x)|^2 |x-y|^{-a}\mathrm d^2 x=\int_{\mathbb R^2}|f(x)|^2 |x|^{-a}\mathrm d^2 x=\int_0^\infty \int_{\partial\mathbb B(0,r)}|f(x)|^2|x|^{-a}~\mathrm d^1 x~\mathrm dr \\ =\int_0^\infty 2\pi r~{\phi(r)}^2~r^{-a}\mathrm dr \\ =\int_0^\infty \psi(r)~r^{-a}\mathrm dr$$
So the question is now, can we find a function $\psi:\mathbb R_{\geq 0}\to\mathbb R$ such that $\psi\in L^1(\mathbb R_{\geq 0})$ but the function $r\mapsto \psi(r)r^{-a}$ is not $L^1$, for some $a\in(1,2)$? The answer is of course, yes. Consider $a=3/2$ and
$$\psi(r)=\mathrm e^{-r}$$
You can construct $\phi(r)=\sqrt{\frac{\mathrm e^{-r}}{2\pi r}}$ and see that the associated 2D function
$$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{\mathrm e^{-|x|}}{2\pi|x|}}$$
Is indeed $L^2(\mathbb R^2)$, but however that $\int_{\mathbb R^2}|f(x)|^2|x|^{-a}\mathrm d^2 x$ does not converge.
